# How to transform this foreach to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

What will be analogy of this code with LINQ? Seems to be easy , but really don`t know how

```
private IRoom FindRoom(List<IHotel> hotels,IRoom selectedRoom)
        {
            foreach(var hotel in hotels)
            {
                foreach(var room in hotel.Rooms)
                {
                    if (selectedRoom.Equals(room))
                        return room;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: `hotels.SelectMany(h => h.Rooms).FirstOrDefault(r => r.Equals(selectedRoom));`

Comment: Wouu thanks a lot to you, i had never been using SelectMany in LINQ , but now i know what is it responsible for

Comment: @juharr, why not put an answer? I've just written the same LINQ query, but stopped when I saw your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static IRoom FindRoomLinq(List<IHotel> hotels, IRoom selectedRoom)
{
    return hotels.SelectMany((hotel) => hotel.Rooms).FirstOrDefault(room => selectedRoom.Equals(room));
}
```

The `.SelectMany` function flattens and jagged array (collection of collections) and then the `.FirstOrDefault()` function filters through to find the matching room.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private IRoom FindRoom(List<IHotel> hotels,IRoom selectedRoom)
    {
        var hotel = hotels.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Rooms.Any(r => r == selectedRoom));
        if (hotel != null)
        {
          return hotel.Rooms.Single(x => x == selectedRoom);
        }
        else
        {
          return null;
         }
    }
```

Comment: That returns a hotel, not a room.

Comment: @juharr, unfortunately you commented while I was editing. np.